# WebView abre navegador

Tags: java, android, webview

Fiz uma aplicação via WebView no AndroidStudio, tudo tranquilo sem erros mas quando coloco as informações para fazer login no meu webview abre o navegador padrão, gostaria que abrisse no próprio WebView:

```
package com.sirseni.simpleandroidwebviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://meulink.com/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    // Use When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://meulink.com/")) {
                return false;

            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque a linha:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

por:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7309017/6835358)

Comment: Funcionou parceiro, agora outra dúvida, sobre o scroll, não consigo ver algumas opções em baixo, o site fica fixo, teria uma solução?

Comment: Olá @EvertonGouveia, que bom que funcionou! Eu não tenho uma resposta para sua segunda pergunta, mas acredito que [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34972186/6835358) possa ajudar você. Caso não resolva, sugiro criar uma nova pergunta. Grande abraço!