# Webview + videoview abrir vídeos de um HTML e reproduzir na videoview

Tags: html, android, webview

Olha amigos sou novo na plataforma Android
Mas queria um simples exemplo de como abrir um HTML com links de vídeos e os reproduzir diretamente na videoview da minha app
Sou grato a qual quer exemplo q me passar

Comment: Possível duplicata de [WebView abre navegador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210267/webview-abre-navegador)

Comment: Vinicius, tem muito exemplo de webview. É algo muito simples, então certeza que não terá problemas. E caso tiver, faça uma pergunta específica para a dúvida, não apenas "pedindo" código.

Comment: Pesquisa no SOpt: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=WEBVIEW+%5Bandroid%5D%5Bwebview%5D

Answer (score -1):

Olha deixa eu ser mais específico tipo criei uma APP que abre um site de animes localmente, e neste site tem episódios dos animes eu só gostaria de quando o usuário clicar em assistir meu videio fosse exibido dentro de uma vídeoview em vez da webview, sei que existem muitos exemplos de webview mas já procurei e nd.. Igual minha aplicação tem um webview e um videoview quero q a webview carregue o site com os videos ea videoview os exibam

Comment: Não faça uma nova pergunta como uma **Resposta**.  
Crie uma nova pergunta para isso.